# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert UniswapV2: LOCKED

Tags: solidity, blockchain, uniswap, ganache-cli, buidler

I am using this [repo](https://github.com/Austin-Williams/uniswap-flash-swapper/blob/master/README.md) to begin testing UniSwap flash swap contracts. I've installed all dependencies correctly and cleanly.

The project uses ganache-cli, hardhat buidler, and yarn in the terminal and I can use all 3 methods to start up a local chain and I get a different error message with all three. If I use:

ganache-cli -f - `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`
buidler node - `Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account`
yarn start-chain - `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert UniswapV2: LOCKED`

**The repo states to use `yarn start-chain`** so I think that's the one to focus on.

This is what I see in Terminal

```
All contracts have already been compiled, skipping compilation.


  Example

Setting up signer...
  signer: 0x8199Bcbd047e404d6c192969590CB7fCc0CCe2f0

Deploying example contract...
  example contract: 0xEA645fB4c45c22E2E75eD2ABB1fAD9525A7329f8

Testing swap - borrows 1 ETH, paying with ETH

Ensuring that contract can cover fees...
  contract ETH balance 0
  contract will not be able to cover fee, sending from signer...
  signer ETH balance 19228617140000000000
  new contract ETH balance 0

Performing flash swap...
    1) successfully flash swaps


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) Example
       successfully flash swaps:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert UniswapV2: LOCKED
      at HttpProvider.send (node_modules/@nomiclabs/buidler/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:36:34)
      at wrapper_1.wrapSend (node_modules/@nomiclabs/buidler/src/internal/core/providers/accounts.ts:219:21)
      at Proxy.cloningSendWrapper (node_modules/@nomiclabs/buidler/src/internal/core/providers/wrapper.ts:9:12)
      at wrapper_1.wrapSend (node_modules/@nomiclabs/buidler/src/internal/core/providers/gas-providers.ts:23:21)
      at Proxy.cloningSendWrapper (node_modules/@nomiclabs/buidler/src/internal/core/providers/wrapper.ts:9:12)
      at wrapper_1.wrapSend (node_modules/@nomiclabs/buidler/src/internal/core/providers/gas-providers.ts:41:21)
      at Proxy.cloningSendWrapper (node_modules/@nomiclabs/buidler/src/internal/core/providers/wrapper.ts:9:12)
      at EthersProviderWrapper.send (node_modules/@nomiclabs/buidler-ethers/src/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:48)
      at /Users/justinsacco/TESTcointaker1/uniswap-flash-swapper/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:164:35
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: did you send the Approval to the router?

Comment: I think this is being caused because the contract is trying to insert my custom code back into UniSwap's pair contract

Comment: did you figure it out? I'm getting the same "Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account"

Comment: I did figure this out, and the error was exactly what it says. I forget the why exactly I was thinking this, but what happened was the address I was calling was NOT a contract.

However I was running into 3 different errors depending on which command line process I used. I needed to use yarn start-chain with gives me the LOCKED error. Running builder-node was calling something I was not working on. If you can find the solution to the LOCKED error using yarn start-chain let me know